# Layout control that is supported woth Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5

I am looking for a decent layout control that is supported with D5.
Something like https://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExLayoutControl (does not support D5)
But it could be much simpler. It also needs to support Right To Left.

I realy hope for is something like a "TTablePanel" (just like HTML TABLE behavior) that can be used to add rows, cells, auto align controls in cell, have an option for "ColSpan" and "RowSpan" etc...

I even dont need design time support.
I will add my controls in runtime.

Here is a nother example what is should look like: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit591-2004/Pages/layout-examples.html

Comment: It's going to be easier just to buy a time machine and return to the 20th century. Seriously, why do you cripple yourself with ancient tools that are not up to the task?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I was expecting a comment like yours. we have a large legacy application that works just fine for years (since the 20th century) :) I want to add a layout control which could make my life a bit easiyer. and to be honest even the "modern" TGridPanel sucks.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a recommendation or library/tool location finder. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. This is mentioned in the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page; see the section with the numbered list. Good luck.

Comment: @Vlad:  Not sure if you're aware, but earlier versions of DevEx's ExpressLayoutControl worked with D5.  Maybe they could dig one out of their archives for you?

Comment: @MartynA: Yes, they offer that in quite a lot support tickets.

Comment: Usage of tables for layout is deprecated in HTML.

Comment: There is default docking support build in in the VCL. I'm pretty sure D5 already supported it. Explore the docking demo.